# Why is [filepicker] sponsored?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, sponsored-tags

The [filepicker.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filepicker.io) tag is sponsored, so it has an  icon next to it:

[image: Filepicker.io]

However, [filepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filepicker), the tag summary of which specifically states

> Questions about the use of file pickers in general. Not to be confused with [filepicker.io]; use that tag for questions related to that service.

has the icon as well:

[image: Filepicker]

A glance at its tag page reveals that it is sponsored.

...by [Filepicker.io](http://filepicker.io).

So, why? Why does Filepicker.io sponsor the [filepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filepicker) tag if it is "not to be confused with [filepicker.io]"?

Comment: Maybe they got it confused themselves.

Comment: Your reasoning is backwards.  Anybody that knows the proper tag is likely to already know about the product.  They want to target the ones that pick [filepicker].

Comment: @HansPassant I think there's an implied question of "Why do we let companies sponsor tags that aren't about their product?"

Comment: "We" don't have anything to do with it, this is a source of income for SE and they don't ask for our permission.  Odd that these things are not obvious btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nice catch! This was done in error. All fixed. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: What's funny is that this sponsorship expires today...